# I'm stuck on how to proceed with my routefinder

Tags: graph, path-finding

I am creating a routefinder that will use either A* or dijikstra that will only work for public transport in my local area. However I have now ran into a problem where I have no idea where to get a graph for only public transport.

I have tried reading through the google maps API to see if i could create the graph myself but no luck.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.